What's the minimal recommended power for EME on 2.4 Ghz?
As a follow-up to this question and the tremendous increase in availability of 10 and 2.4 Ghz equipment because of the QO100 satellite, I was wondering what the minimal recommended power on 2.4 Ghz is for making successful contacts using JT65/Q65 or something which suits the needs. E.g. given a 0.85m antenna which has around 24 db of gain on 2.4 ghz.
Spoiler: I like to get away with the 10-20 watts we get from those QO100 upverters :)
Or using stacked parabolic antennas I'd be also open...

yes, thanks, corrected

To answer this, you need to make a path loss equation and solve for power.  Path loss equation must include sensitivity of the receiver, data bandwidth, noise floor (including injected noise), power of the transmitter, and attenuation/gain of every component in between.

You've supplied desired transmit power and frequency.  We can guess at path loss of the trip to the moon and back including moon's reflectivity.  Bandwidth and data rate of jt65 is known.  All the rest you need to supply.

Thanks, I've used this tool https://wettersat.bplaced.net/EME/EME.html it seems I can get away with 12 watt and a 125 cm dish if the other end has a 5m dish
